# How can I force Qt to call `data()` on my model?

Tags: qt4

I've got a `QtTreeView` and a class `Foo` derived from `QAbstractItemModel` attached to it.

In `Foo::data` I set the `Qt::BackgroundRole` for each element of the tree according to the status of some internal data.

When I receive a signal to update my internal data I would like to update the background of each item accordingly, but I can't seem to reliably make Qt call my `Foo::data` method.

I've tried calling `update()` and `repaint()` (on the view), to no avail. Calling `reset()` works but I lose all the state of the tree (e.g. expanded elements etc.). Calling `setData()` on each element also works but the code gets a bit awkward as I have to explicitly rebuild the tree of data displayed which is not nice.

How can I force Qt to call `data()` on my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inform the view class your model has changed, by emitting the [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal.

Comment: Unfortunately `dataChanged` requires explicit indices, which are "difficult" for me to recover. I only have the indices of the top level elements, and reconstructing the entire hierarchy would be expensive. I just want `data()` to be called again for all items.

Comment: Without wishing to seem rude, if recovering the indices for your items is difficult, you might want to reconsider your design, or maintain some kind of additional structure so you *can* recover indices. Many model operations assume you can easily map to/from a QModelIndex.

Comment: No offense taken. To clarify: it wasn't difficult for me to recover the indices, but "lengthy" for me to recover *all* the items explicitly from scratch rather than implicitly through parent/child relationships. Luckily I just need to find out the first and the last one, so the code ends up being fairly compact. I still think that qt could do with a allDataChanged() signal though!

Answer (score 2):

Try beginResetModel() when you start to modify data and then endResetModel(), but remember that your view/model will have poor performance on each change, because whole model will be queried and painted again

Answer (score 1):

Futher to James Turner's correct answer, here's some additional code for future 
reference. To signal that all data has changed, one needs to retrieve the 
indices of the first and the last item.

The first item is trivial:

```
QModelIndex FooModel::firstIndex() const
{
    return index( 0, 0 );
}
```

The last item is trivial as well for a single level hierarchy:

```
QModelIndex FooModel::lastIndex() const
{
    QModelIndex lastTopLevelIndex = index( rowCount() - 1, 0 );
    return index( rowCount( lastTopLevelIndex ) - 1, kNumColumns, lastTopLevelIndex );
}
```

and a bit more complex in the general case:

```
QModelIndex FooModel::lastIndex() const
{
    QModelIndex parent;
    QModelIndex candidate;
    QModelIndex lastIndex;
    int row = rowCount();

    while ( row > 0 )
    {
        parent = index( row - 1, 0, parent );
        candidate = index( row - 1, kNumColumns, parent );
        row = rowCount( parent );
    }

    return candidate;
}
```

(I'm not sure if it's important to always have the parent on the first column or not...)